# Gunicorn error: "Error opening file for reading: Permission denied"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, django, gunicorn

I'm getting an error when running my Django app with gunicorn: when I make a post request over 7800 bytes I see the following error from gunicorn:

```
"Error opening file for reading: Permission denied".
```

It then drops the request and nginx is getting a "Connection reset by peer" error.

This doesn't happen if I run the Django development server instead. Strangely, if I make the request to an invalid URL, no matter what the post content length, I get the standard Django debug webpage.

So it seems to be how gunicorn is handling something that Django is doing when it's processing a request for a valid view URL.

This is being run on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried running Gunicorn as root and it still happens.

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to debug this any further. I've tried setting the tmp_upload_dir to a directory will full permissions incase that was an issue, but no luck.

Any advice would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the host in the ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    'stage.domain.com',
    'domain.com',
)
```

I would expect a more descriptive error message, but unfortunately, this is what we get.

Comment: I don't think it's this because I'm running with `DEBUG=True`

Comment: It's not a production server, just another development machine running gunicorn.

Comment: yeah this didn't fix it for me either, I had the proper allowed hosts in there already.  What did it was running chown -R my_id:my_gid * on my entire django project. It should be the same user/group used to run gunicorn i.e. --user --group in your conf file, or by default its the user you are logged in as.